# Satellite Assembly deployment

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I am trying to localize my windows phone 7 application using satellite Assemblies. I have built

```
(al /t:lib /embed:stringlibrary.it-It.resx /culture:it /out:PhoneApp2.resources.dll /template:PhoneApp2.dll)
```

a dll "PhoneApp2.resources.dll" for my application PhoneApp2 from a resource file `stringlibrary.it-It.resx` and then i downloaded the dll
using webclient and stored in a directory it-IT from app PhoneApp2 .Now the dll resides in phoneapp2's isolatedstorage.

I have another resource file stringlibrary.resx which always gets compiled with application and had entries for english support(default).

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("it-IT\\"+resfile, System.IO.FileMode.Create, file))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while (e.Result.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
    {
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }

}
```

I have the entry [assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute("it-IT", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)] in assembly file as well.

It always shows me neutral language text (english) in the Messagebox even though the current language and culture is italian.
That means it is not able to find the satellite assembly.

```
rm = new ResourceManager("PhoneApp2.stringlibrary", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
string greeting = rm.GetString("String1");
MessageBox.Show(greeting);
```

But if i compile `stringlibrary.it-It.resx` with PhoneApp2 instead of satellite assembly, the Messagebox displays the italian text properly 
when culture is italian and english for english cuture. Am i missing something in deploying satellite assemblies? Pls let me know.

Regards,
Senthil

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use assemblys in your App you have downloaded into the isolated storage. Only assemblys signed by Microsoft (thus those assemblys already in your XAP on submission) can be loaded / executed on runtime.

If you want to download additional translations afterwards you should go with resx-files or any other format you can then parse on your own. My suggestion would be to use some kind of database for all resource strings and then add the newsly downloaded data into this db. This is way more flexible then what you are trying to accomplish :)

Comment: OK. Thanks for the information. I shall try to download the resx files directly and parse it.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried localizing in the way that you're doing it.  To me it seems overly complicated.  But I have localized several apps, and given that I had a hard time finding a complete source how to do it, I blogged it.  Here's my blog: http://hopnet.mobi/website/Blog.aspx

Basically you do this:

1. Create the project
2. Edit the .csproj file in notepad to add the desired cultures to the tag.
3. Select a neutral culture in the project's properties
4. Add Resources to the project in Solution Explorer
5. Create a class to access those resources
6. Add that class to the tag of the App.xaml file
7. Put your strings into the Resources file
8. Bind to those strings using the resource binding in your xaml.
9. If using an ApplicationBar, you must do so in code, as it cannot be bound in xaml.
10. Create another resource file for each supported culture.
11. Create dll files for each supported language, so the title will be correct on the tile and program list.

Comment: Thanks for the information. i have already done whatever steps that you have described and it works fine.But now i want to give user the option to download the dll(resource file) so that there will be only few set of DLLs.I am doing this inorder to minimize the size of .xap file.

Comment: The procedure you have described and the one i have already done will always include all the DLLs. But i want to have settings button where in user can select the cultures and only those DLLs will be downloaded from a webserver and stored in isolated storage of app as per the directory structure defined by [assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute("it-IT", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite) .

Comment: This will look for it-IT directory for Italian language resource file. Hope i have made it clear as what i want to do